# Output doesn't come for REST API Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am working on the tutorial to build an AngularJs app where I am fetching information of users. When I am running the app and the output doesn't display.

My index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myContactApp" >
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <script src="appConfig.service.js"></script>
            <script src="appname.service.js"></script>
            <script src="contact.controller.js"></script>
            <script src="contactdata.service.js"></script>

            <title>My Contact Application</title>
    </head>

    <body>



        <main>
        <div class='container' ng-controller="contactController as ctrl">
            <div class='row'>
                <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="con in ctrl.contactArr" data-ng-click="ctrl.selectUser($index)">
                            <span>{{con.name.first+ " "+con.name.last}}</span>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">

                        <a href="#">
                            <img data-ng-src="{{ctrl.selectedUser.picture.medium}}">
                        </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ctrl.selectedUser.name.first+ " "+ctrl.selectedUser.name.last}}</h4>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <h6>Location</h6>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                {{ctrl.selectedUser.location.street+" "+ctrl.selectedUser.location.city+" "+ctrl.selectedUser.location.state+" "+ctrl.selectedUser.location.postcode}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                 <h6>Phone</h6>
                                </p>
                            <p>{{ctrl.selectedUser.phone}}</p>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <h6>email</h6>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                {{ctrl.selectedUser.email}}</p>



                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    </body>

</html>
```

My app.js

```
 var app=angular.module("myContactApp",[]);
```

My appconfig.service.js

```
    (function(){

var app=angular.module("myContactApp");

app.service("AppDataServiceSVC",function(appNameSVC){
    this.Name=appNameSVC;
    this.author='Bhaskar';
    this.buildDate=new Date().toDateString();

});
})();
```

My appname.service.js file :-

```
   (function (){
var app=angular.module("myContactApp");
app.value("AppNameSVC","My New Contact List");
})();
```

My contact.controller.js file

```
(function(){

    var app=angular.module("myContactApp");

    app.controller("contactController",contactCtrl);

    function contactCtrl(ContactDataSVC){
    var self=this;
    ContactDataSVC.getContacts().then(function(data){
       self.contacts=data;
   })



                    this.selectUser=function(index){
                        this.selectedUser = this.contactArr[index];
                    }

}
})();
```

My contactdata.service.js

```
(function(){

    var app=angular.module("myContactApp");

    app.service("ContactDataSVC",function($http){
        var self=this;
        self.getContacts=function(){
        var response1=$http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts');
        var response2=response1.then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
        return response2;
    }
    });
    })();
```

I have created db.json which I am running on json-server and using it as REST API. It should display contact details but it doesn't display anything on the browser. I am unable to figure out where I have made the mistake.

Comment: when you `curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/contacts` what response do you get?

Comment: You're not injecting `ContactDataSvc` into `contactController`. Also the scope variable you're accessing in your template is `contactArr` yet in your `contactController` you're setting `contacts` when it's gotten from the service.

Comment: Thanks I just found that that this was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you use: `self.contacts=data;`

Change `ng-repeat="con in ctrl.contactArr"` to:

```
ng-repeat="con in ctrl.contacts"
```

---

also pass `con` to `selectUser` : `data-ng-click="ctrl.selectUser(con)"`

<kbd>[Demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FTk9TYKZCUPwv3mlnW1f?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Yes its a typo but still issue is resolved partially as my click functionality is not working. I am looking for any such mistake. Thanks for your reply.